# What does 'void' in typescript mean?

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I came across online, and I am wondering what does `void` imply in Typescript?

Just like here:

```
private _handleProjectQuerySuccess(data: IProject[]): void  
{
    data.sort(this._projectSort);

    var pathname = this._$location.path();

    var activeSet = false;
    data.forEach((project: IProject) =>
    {
        project.active = pathname == '/' + project.id;
        activeSet      = activeSet || project.active;

        project.name        = this._$sanitize(project.name);
        project.description = this._$sanitize(project.description);
        project.url         = this._$sce.trustAsUrl(project.url);
        project.readme      = this._$sce.trustAsHtml(project.readme);

        project.title = project.name + (project.fork ? ' (fork)' : ' (repo)');

        this._scope.projects.push(project);

        this._projectMap[project.id] = this._scope.projects[this._scope.projects.length - 1];
    });

    if (!activeSet)
    {
        data[0].active = true;
    }
}
```

After we declared private, we implied **`void`**... What does that mean?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is just a type, as documented here:

#### [Void](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#void)

> Perhaps the opposite in some ways to 'any' is 'void', the absence of having any type at all. You may commonly see this as the return type of functions that do not return a value:

```
function warnUser(): void {
    alert("This is my warning message");
}
```

Comment: So it implies that function, is of a type 'void'? Or it returns void?

Comment: The standard typescript way how to declare type is to use colon `:` - this notation: `name:string` or `func:Function`... so if we want to explicitly declare returned type of a function we use the same notation. So the answer: it is the retunred value type

Comment: Now that TypeScript has `never`, this seems obsolete

Answer (score 0):

Important to note that `void` and `any` types overlap a bit, which may be weird at first. While `void` may return no data (only `null` and `undefined`) - `any` may return **any kind of data** (including `null` and `undefined`).